# How to detect any type of variable that is stored in an array - Godot?

Tags: types, godot, gdscript

I have an array containing nodes as well as strings. While passing it through a loop, I want to call certain functions depending on the type of object being read. I tried to do the following to test the type -

```
if to_fry_array[fry_looper].is_class("Node2D"):
    to_fry_array[fry_looper].show()
else:
    print (to_fry_array[fry_looper])
```

The code throws an error when a string is read in the array `to_fry_array`. Error -

> Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'is_class' in base 'String'.

How do I modify this code so that it behaves universal to all types of objects/variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every type has method `is_class`, but fortunately you can use operator `typeof` to achieve what you need.

```
if typeof(obj) == TYPE_OBJECT and obj.is_class("Node2D"):
    print("Node2D: ", obj)
elif typeof(x) == TYPE_STRING:
    print("String: ", obj)
```

and in your particular case:

```
if typeof(to_fry_array[fry_looper]) == TYPE_OBJECT and \
          to_fry_array[fry_looper].is_class("Node2D"):
    to_fry_array[fry_looper].show()
else:
    print (to_fry_array[fry_looper])
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

*is_class()* function was introduced in Godot 3.0

If that function is not identified then probably you are using an older version

I suggest using *get_class()* or *typeof()* functions as an alternative.

Research Links:

- [Godot API Docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-is-class)
- [Similar Question asked in Godot Community](https://godotengine.org/qa/13029/is-there-a-corresponding-type-function-in-gdscript)

Comment: I am using Godot3.0 The function works for a class of "Node" but not "String".
get_class()  dooes not work and throw an error. I will check for typeof()